# Are these sets equipotent?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I need to decide which of these three sets are equipotent:

$M_1=\{(n_1,n_2,n_3)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\ |\ n_1+n_2=n_3\}$

$M_2 = \{M\in P(\mathbb{Z})\ |\ 0\in M\}$

$M_3 = \cup _{a\in\mathbb{Z}}\{x\in\mathbb{R}\ |\ a\leq x < \frac{2a+1}{2}\}$

I want to prove (or disprove) the equipotency by finding injections to and from $\mathbb{N}$, $P(\mathbb{N})$ and $\mathbb{R}$ (Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein).

I've already proven that $M_1$ is equipotent to $\mathbb{N}$:

1) $M_1\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, $(n_1,n_2,n_3)\mapsto 2^{n_1}\cdot 3^{n_2}\cdot 5^{n_3}$

2) $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow M_2, n\mapsto (n,n,2n)$

I'm stuck finding injections like this for $M_2$ and $M_3$.

It already seems that $M_2$ is equipotent to $P(\mathbb{N})$ and $M_3$ is equipotent to $\mathbb{R}$, but what are the corresponding injections?

Comment: You don't need actual functions to *use* CSB theorem, so : did you really mean you can use it?

Comment: @DonAntonio: Yes, I can use it. But how do I use CSB without giving two injections?

Comment: Just using inequalities between cardinalities of well known sets and usinmg arithmetic of cardinals, of course. This is, I believe, the greatest thing about this theorem

Comment: @DonAntonio: Can you give an example please?

Comment: @de For example: $$\aleph_0=|\Bbb N|\le |\Bbb N\times\Bbb N|\le\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0=\aleph_0\implies|\Bbb N\times\Bbb N|=\aleph_0$$

Comment: @DonAntonio: Oh, I didn't know that. But I'm afraid I'm not allowed to use that since we explicitly introduced CSB for this assignment by giving two explicit injections like in my example above. Is it possible to find such injections for the other two sets?

Comment: I guess it is possible, but without using the full strangth of CSB I am not sure which injections or bijections could we use...Perhaps later I, or someone else, can come up with something.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I stand corrected, I am allowed to use arithmetic of cardinals. Doing that I was able to prove that $|M_3|=|\mathbb{R}|$. Can you perhaps give a hint how to approach $M_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since for any set $\;X\in P(\Bbb N)\;$ (for me the naturals do **not** contain zero) , we have that $\;X\cup\{0\}\in M_2\;$ , so we have that

$$\mathfrak c=|P(\Bbb N)|\le|M_2|\le|P(\Bbb Z)|=\mathfrak c\implies |M_2|=\mathfrak c$$

Comment: Unfortunately, we defined the naturals _including_ zero. I guess it's a little more tricky this way, since the first inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: Well, then just define $\;\Bbb T:=\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}\;$ and you get **exactly the same** as, of course, $\;|\Bbb T|=|\Bbb N|\;$